# Replacing string in multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array which has 4 element each. And I want to replace the same element before with empty string.

```
arr1 = [
    ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Manual", "$ 120,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Manual", "$ 134,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Automatic", "$ 140,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Automatic", "$ 150,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Focus", "Manual", "$ 330,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Focus", "Manual", "$ 335,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Focus", "Manual", "$ 350,000,000"],
    ["Ford", "Focus", "Automatic", "$ 360,000,000"],
    ["VW", "Golf", "Manual", "$ 350,000,000"],
    ["VW", "Golf", "Automatic", "$ 370,000,000"]
];
```

So the result would be like :

```
[
    ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Manual", "$ 120,000,000"],
    ["", "", "", "$ 134,000,000"],
    ["", "", "Automatic", "$ 140,000,000"],
    ["", "", "", "$ 150,000,000"],
    ["", "Focus", "Manual", "$ 330,000,000"],
    ["", "", "", "$ 335,000,000"],
    ["", "", "", "$ 350,000,000"],
    ["", "", "Automatic", "$ 360,000,000"],
    ["VW", "Golf", "Manual", "$ 350,000,000"],
    ["", "", "Automatic", "$ 370,000,000"]
];
```

I have tried to create new array which include all the unique element, and loop it and then append it into 3rd array

```
arr2 = ["Ford", "Fiesta", "Focus", "Manual", "Automatic", "VW", "Golf"],
arr3 = []
print('-----------------------------------')
for x in arr1 :
  print("X[0] ", x[0])
  print("X[1] ", x[1])
  print("X[2] ", x[2])
  print("X[3] ", x[3])
  if(x[0] == arr1[0][0]):
    arr3.append("")
    if(x[1] == arr1[0][1]):
      arr3.append("")
      if(x[2] == arr1[0][2]):
        arr3.append("")
      if(x[2] != arr1[0][2]):
        arr3.append(x[2])
  arr3.append(x[3])
```

But my result only correct for the 2nd row :

```
['', '', '', '$ 120,000,000', 
'', '', '', '$ 134,000,000', 
'', '', 'Automatic', '$ 140,000,000', 
'', '', 'Automatic', '$ 150,000,000', 
'', '$ 330,000,000', '', '$ 335,000,000', 
'', '$ 350,000,000', '', '$ 360,000,000', 
'$ 350,000,000', '$ 370,000,000']
```

Can someone tell me where my mistake please? Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a "vertical" problem, so I suggest you process one column at a time.  That way, you can keep the last unique value as you go down the rows, and when it's the same, erase the cell, and when it's different, the value becomes the new unique value.  But again, probably easiest to process a single column at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a new array you can add the first row to it because you know the first row will not be changed. Then you loop the first array to check every row and adding them to the new array.

Something like this should work:

```
arr2 = []
arr2.append(arr1[0])
for i in range(0,len(arr1)-1):
    tmp = []
    for v in range(len(arr1[i])):
        if arr1[i+1][v] == arr1[i][v]:
            tmp.append("")
        else:
            tmp.append(arr1[i+1][v])
    arr2.append(tmp)

print(arr2)
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining why you're using range + len? I still dont get it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using range + len so I get the index (`i`) of the value. That way  can do `i+1` that will be the row after the current row. The same for `v`, I check every cell on two rows in that loop.

Comment: Its like my method, but you have different ways. I was struggling on comparing the value. Anyway, thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some transpositioning and `itetools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

res = zip(*[chain(*([next(g)] + [""] * len(list(g)) 
                    for _, g in groupby(col))) 
            for col in zip(*arr1)])
for line in res:
    print(line)

('Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Manual', '$ 120,000,000')
('', '', '', '$ 134,000,000')
('', '', 'Automatic', '$ 140,000,000')
('', '', '', '$ 150,000,000')
('', 'Focus', 'Manual', '$ 330,000,000')
('', '', '', '$ 335,000,000')
('', '', '', '$ 350,000,000')
('', '', 'Automatic', '$ 360,000,000')
('VW', 'Golf', 'Manual', '$ 350,000,000')
('', '', 'Automatic', '$ 370,000,000')
```